# Django widget in forms is not working correctly

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm using django widgets into my forms.py for the content field. But whenever I change the column and rows in forms.py with the widgets it's not changing in the template.

My forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Comment


class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Text goes here', 'rows': '4', 'cols': '10'}))
        fields = ('content',)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fields must be defined outside of `Meta`:

```py
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Text goes here', 'rows': '4', 'cols': '10'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('content',)
```

Also, if you only want to customize the widget you can use the `widgets` meta:

```py
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('content',)
        widgets = {
            'content': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Text goes here', 'rows': '4', 'cols': '10'})
        }
```

Check the [overriding the default fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) section of the Django documentation for further details.

Comment: **Thank You Very Much.**